# OpenLayers 5: move marker smoothly

Tags: openlayers-5

I use
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html

**code snippet:**

```js
// This long string is placed here due to jsFiddle limitations.
// It is usually loaded with AJAX.
var polyline = [
  'hldhx@lnau`BCG_EaC??cFjAwDjF??uBlKMd@}@z@??aC^yk@z_@se@b[wFdE??wFfE}N',
  'fIoGxB_I\\gG}@eHoCyTmPqGaBaHOoD\\??yVrGotA|N??o[N_STiwAtEmHGeHcAkiA}^',
  'aMyBiHOkFNoI`CcVvM??gG^gF_@iJwC??eCcA]OoL}DwFyCaCgCcCwDcGwHsSoX??wI_E',
  'kUFmq@hBiOqBgTwS??iYse@gYq\\cp@ce@{vA}s@csJqaE}{@iRaqE{lBeRoIwd@_T{]_',
  'Ngn@{PmhEwaA{SeF_u@kQuyAw]wQeEgtAsZ}LiCarAkVwI}D??_}RcjEinPspDwSqCgs@',
  'sPua@_OkXaMeT_Nwk@ob@gV}TiYs[uTwXoNmT{Uyb@wNg]{Nqa@oDgNeJu_@_G}YsFw]k',
  'DuZyDmm@i_@uyIJe~@jCg|@nGiv@zUi_BfNqaAvIow@dEed@dCcf@r@qz@Egs@{Acu@mC',
  'um@yIey@gGig@cK_m@aSku@qRil@we@{mAeTej@}Tkz@cLgr@aHko@qOmcEaJw~C{w@ka',
  'i@qBchBq@kmBS{kDnBscBnFu_Dbc@_~QHeU`IuyDrC_}@bByp@fCyoA?qMbD}{AIkeAgB',
  'k_A_A{UsDke@gFej@qH{o@qGgb@qH{`@mMgm@uQus@kL{_@yOmd@ymBgwE}x@ouBwtA__',
  'DuhEgaKuWct@gp@cnBii@mlBa_@}|Asj@qrCg^eaC}L{dAaJ_aAiOyjByH{nAuYu`GsAw',
  'Xyn@ywMyOyqD{_@cfIcDe}@y@aeBJmwA`CkiAbFkhBlTgdDdPyiB`W}xDnSa}DbJyhCrX',
  'itAhT}x@bE}Z_@qW_Kwv@qKaaAiBgXvIm}A~JovAxCqW~WanB`XewBbK{_A`K}fBvAmi@',
  'xBycBeCauBoF}}@qJioAww@gjHaPopA_NurAyJku@uGmi@cDs[eRaiBkQstAsQkcByNma',
  'CsK_uBcJgbEw@gkB_@ypEqDoqSm@eZcDwjBoGw`BoMegBaU_`Ce_@_uBqb@ytBwkFqiT_',
  'fAqfEwe@mfCka@_eC_UmlB}MmaBeWkkDeHwqAoX}~DcBsZmLcxBqOwqE_DkyAuJmrJ\\o',
  '~CfIewG|YibQxBssB?es@qGciA}RorAoVajA_nAodD{[y`AgPqp@mKwr@ms@umEaW{dAm',
  'b@umAw|@ojBwzDaaJsmBwbEgdCsrFqhAihDquAi`Fux@}_Dui@_eB_u@guCuyAuiHukA_',
  'lKszAu|OmaA{wKm}@clHs_A_rEahCssKo\\sgBsSglAqk@yvDcS_wAyTwpBmPc|BwZknF',
  'oFscB_GsaDiZmyMyLgtHgQonHqT{hKaPg}Dqq@m~Hym@c`EuiBudIabB{hF{pWifx@snA',
  'w`GkFyVqf@y~BkoAi}Lel@wtc@}`@oaXi_C}pZsi@eqGsSuqJ|Lqeb@e]kgPcaAu}SkDw',
  'zGhn@gjYh\\qlNZovJieBqja@ed@siO{[ol\\kCmjMe\\isHorCmec@uLebB}EqiBaCg}',
  '@m@qwHrT_vFps@kkI`uAszIrpHuzYxx@e{Crw@kpDhN{wBtQarDy@knFgP_yCu\\wyCwy',
  'A{kHo~@omEoYmoDaEcPiuAosDagD}rO{{AsyEihCayFilLaiUqm@_bAumFo}DgqA_uByi',
  '@swC~AkzDlhA}xEvcBa}Cxk@ql@`rAo|@~bBq{@``Bye@djDww@z_C_cAtn@ye@nfC_eC',
  '|gGahH~s@w}@``Fi~FpnAooC|u@wlEaEedRlYkrPvKerBfYs}Arg@m}AtrCkzElw@gjBb',
  'h@woBhR{gCwGkgCc[wtCuOapAcFoh@uBy[yBgr@c@iq@o@wvEv@sp@`FajBfCaq@fIipA',
  'dy@ewJlUc`ExGuaBdEmbBpBssArAuqBBg}@s@g{AkB{bBif@_bYmC}r@kDgm@sPq_BuJ_',
  's@{X_{AsK_d@eM{d@wVgx@oWcu@??aDmOkNia@wFoSmDyMyCkPiBePwAob@XcQ|@oNdCo',
  'SfFwXhEmOnLi\\lbAulB`X_d@|k@au@bc@oc@bqC}{BhwDgcD`l@ed@??bL{G|a@eTje@',
  'oS~]cLr~Bgh@|b@}Jv}EieAlv@sPluD{z@nzA_]`|KchCtd@sPvb@wSb{@ko@f`RooQ~e',
  '[upZbuIolI|gFafFzu@iq@nMmJ|OeJn^{Qjh@yQhc@uJ~j@iGdd@kAp~BkBxO{@|QsAfY',
  'gEtYiGd]}Jpd@wRhVoNzNeK`j@ce@vgK}cJnSoSzQkVvUm^rSgc@`Uql@xIq\\vIgg@~k',
  'Dyq[nIir@jNoq@xNwc@fYik@tk@su@neB}uBhqEesFjoGeyHtCoD|D}Ed|@ctAbIuOzqB',
  '_}D~NgY`\\um@v[gm@v{Cw`G`w@o{AdjAwzBh{C}`Gpp@ypAxn@}mAfz@{bBbNia@??jI',
  'ab@`CuOlC}YnAcV`@_^m@aeB}@yk@YuTuBg^uCkZiGk\\yGeY}Lu_@oOsZiTe[uWi[sl@',
  'mo@soAauAsrBgzBqgAglAyd@ig@asAcyAklA}qAwHkGi{@s~@goAmsAyDeEirB_{B}IsJ',
  'uEeFymAssAkdAmhAyTcVkFeEoKiH}l@kp@wg@sj@ku@ey@uh@kj@}EsFmG}Jk^_r@_f@m',
  '~@ym@yjA??a@cFd@kBrCgDbAUnAcBhAyAdk@et@??kF}D??OL'
].join('');

var route = /** @type {module:ol/geom/LineString~LineString} */ (new ol.format.Polyline({
  factor: 1e6
}).readGeometry(polyline, {
  dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
  featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
}));

var routeCoords = route.getCoordinates();
var routeLength = routeCoords.length;

var routeFeature = new ol.Feature({
  type: 'route',
  geometry: route
});
var geoMarker = new ol.Feature({
  type: 'geoMarker',
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(routeCoords[0])
});
var startMarker = new ol.Feature({
  type: 'icon',
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(routeCoords[0])
});
var endMarker = new ol.Feature({
  type: 'icon',
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(routeCoords[routeLength - 1])
});

var styles = {
  'route': new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      width: 6,
      color: [237, 212, 0, 0.8]
    })
  }),
  'icon': new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      anchor: [0.5, 1],
      src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/data/icon.png'
    })
  }),
  'geoMarker': new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({ // CircleStyle({
      radius: 7,
      snapToPixel: false,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'black'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'white',
        width: 2
      })
    })
  })
};

var animating = false;
var speed, now;
var speedInput = document.getElementById('speed');
var startButton = document.getElementById('start-animation');

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({ // VectorLayer({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({ // VectorSource({
    features: [routeFeature, geoMarker, startMarker, endMarker]
  }),
  style: function(feature) {
    // hide geoMarker if animation is active
    if (animating && feature.get('type') === 'geoMarker') {
      return null;
    }
    return styles[feature.get('type')];
  }
});

var center = [-5639523.95, -3501274.52];
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: document.getElementById('map'),
  loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
  view: new ol.View({
    center: center,
    zoom: 9,
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 19
  }),
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({ // TileLayer({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    vectorLayer
  ]
});

var moveFeature = function(event) {
  var vectorContext = event.vectorContext;
  var frameState = event.frameState;

  if (animating) {
    var elapsedTime = frameState.time - now;
    // here the trick to increase speed is to jump some indexes
    // on lineString coordinates
    var index = Math.round(speed * elapsedTime / 1000);

    if (index >= routeLength) {
      stopAnimation(true);
      return;
    }

    var currentPoint = new ol.geom.Point(routeCoords[index]);
    var feature = new ol.Feature(currentPoint);
    vectorContext.drawFeature(feature, styles.geoMarker);
  }
  // tell OpenLayers to continue the postcompose animation
  map.render();
};

function startAnimation() {
  if (animating) {
    stopAnimation(false);
  } else {
    animating = true;
    now = new Date().getTime();
    speed = speedInput.value;
    startButton.textContent = 'Cancel Animation';
    // hide geoMarker
    geoMarker.setStyle(null);
    // just in case you pan somewhere else
    map.getView().setCenter(center);
    map.on('postcompose', moveFeature);
    map.render();
  }
}


/**
 * @param {boolean} ended end of animation.
 */
function stopAnimation(ended) {
  animating = false;
  startButton.textContent = 'Start Animation';

  // if animation cancelled set the marker at the beginning
  var coord = ended ? routeCoords[routeLength - 1] : routeCoords[0];
  /** @type {module:ol/geom/Point~Point} */
  (geoMarker.getGeometry())
  .setCoordinates(coord);
  //remove listener
  map.un('postcompose', moveFeature);
}

startButton.addEventListener('click', startAnimation, false);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.map {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.1.3/build/ol.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<label for="speed">
      speed:&nbsp;
      <input id="speed" type="range" min="10" max="999" step="10" value="60">
    </label>
<button id="start-animation">Start Animation</button>
```

but I need to move marker smoothly between two point (or many)

Answer (score 2):

See [ol-ext](http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/doc/doc-pages/index.html) : [featureAnimation](http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/doc/doc-pages/ol.featureAnimation.html)

[example from that library's documentation](http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/animation/map.featureanimation.path.html)

**code snippet (example from the OpenLayers documentation using ol-ext):**

```js
// use window.onload so can move encoded polyline definition to bottom
window.onload = function() {
  var route = /** @type {module:ol/geom/LineString~LineString} */ (new ol.format.Polyline({
    factor: 1e6
  }).readGeometry(polyline, {
    dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
  }));

  var routeCoords = route.getCoordinates();
  var routeLength = routeCoords.length;

  var routePts = new ol.Feature({
    type: 'route',
    geometry: new ol.geom.MultiPoint(routeCoords)
  });

  var routeFeature = new ol.Feature({
    type: 'route',
    geometry: route
  });
  var geoMarker = new ol.Feature({
    type: 'geoMarker',
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(routeCoords[0])
  });
  var startMarker = new ol.Feature({
    type: 'icon',
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(routeCoords[0])
  });
  var endMarker = new ol.Feature({
    type: 'icon',
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(routeCoords[routeLength - 1])
  });

  var styles = {
    'route': new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        width: 6,
        color: [237, 212, 0, 0.8]
      }),
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 1,
        snapToPixel: false,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'red'
        })
      })
    }),
    'icon': new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Icon({
        anchor: [0.5, 1],
        src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/data/icon.png'
      })
    }),
    'geoMarker': new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({ // CircleStyle({
        radius: 7,
        snapToPixel: false,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'black'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'white',
          width: 2
        })
      })
    })
  };

  var animating = false;
  var speed, now;
  var speedInput = document.getElementById('speed');
  var startButton = document.getElementById('start-animation');

  var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({ // VectorLayer({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({ // VectorSource({
      features: [routePts, routeFeature, geoMarker, startMarker, endMarker]
    }),
    style: function(feature) {
      return styles[feature.get('type')];
    }
  });

  var center = [-5639523.95, -3501274.52];
  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
    loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
    view: new ol.View({
      center: center,
      zoom: 9,
      minZoom: 2,
      maxZoom: 19
    }),
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({ // TileLayer({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      }),
      vectorLayer
    ]
  });
  console.log("init speed=" + speedInput.value / 100);

  function startAnimation() {
    if (animating) animating.stop();
    console.log("update speed=" + Number(speedInput.value) / 100);
    // anim.set("speed", Number(speedInput.value)/10);
    var anim = new ol.featureAnimation.Path({
      path: route,
      easing: ol.easing.linear,
      speed: Number(speedInput.value) / 100
    });

    animating = vectorLayer.animateFeature(geoMarker, anim);
  }
  geoMarker.on('change', function() {
    map.getView().setCenter(geoMarker.getGeometry().getCoordinates());
  });

  startButton.addEventListener('click', startAnimation, false);
}
// This long string is placed here due to jsFiddle limitations.
// It is usually loaded with AJAX.
var polyline = [
  'hldhx@lnau`BCG_EaC??cFjAwDjF??uBlKMd@}@z@??aC^yk@z_@se@b[wFdE??wFfE}N',
  'fIoGxB_I\\gG}@eHoCyTmPqGaBaHOoD\\??yVrGotA|N??o[N_STiwAtEmHGeHcAkiA}^',
  'aMyBiHOkFNoI`CcVvM??gG^gF_@iJwC??eCcA]OoL}DwFyCaCgCcCwDcGwHsSoX??wI_E',
  'kUFmq@hBiOqBgTwS??iYse@gYq\\cp@ce@{vA}s@csJqaE}{@iRaqE{lBeRoIwd@_T{]_',
  'Ngn@{PmhEwaA{SeF_u@kQuyAw]wQeEgtAsZ}LiCarAkVwI}D??_}RcjEinPspDwSqCgs@',
  'sPua@_OkXaMeT_Nwk@ob@gV}TiYs[uTwXoNmT{Uyb@wNg]{Nqa@oDgNeJu_@_G}YsFw]k',
  'DuZyDmm@i_@uyIJe~@jCg|@nGiv@zUi_BfNqaAvIow@dEed@dCcf@r@qz@Egs@{Acu@mC',
  'um@yIey@gGig@cK_m@aSku@qRil@we@{mAeTej@}Tkz@cLgr@aHko@qOmcEaJw~C{w@ka',
  'i@qBchBq@kmBS{kDnBscBnFu_Dbc@_~QHeU`IuyDrC_}@bByp@fCyoA?qMbD}{AIkeAgB',
  'k_A_A{UsDke@gFej@qH{o@qGgb@qH{`@mMgm@uQus@kL{_@yOmd@ymBgwE}x@ouBwtA__',
  'DuhEgaKuWct@gp@cnBii@mlBa_@}|Asj@qrCg^eaC}L{dAaJ_aAiOyjByH{nAuYu`GsAw',
  'Xyn@ywMyOyqD{_@cfIcDe}@y@aeBJmwA`CkiAbFkhBlTgdDdPyiB`W}xDnSa}DbJyhCrX',
  'itAhT}x@bE}Z_@qW_Kwv@qKaaAiBgXvIm}A~JovAxCqW~WanB`XewBbK{_A`K}fBvAmi@',
  'xBycBeCauBoF}}@qJioAww@gjHaPopA_NurAyJku@uGmi@cDs[eRaiBkQstAsQkcByNma',
  'CsK_uBcJgbEw@gkB_@ypEqDoqSm@eZcDwjBoGw`BoMegBaU_`Ce_@_uBqb@ytBwkFqiT_',
  'fAqfEwe@mfCka@_eC_UmlB}MmaBeWkkDeHwqAoX}~DcBsZmLcxBqOwqE_DkyAuJmrJ\\o',
  '~CfIewG|YibQxBssB?es@qGciA}RorAoVajA_nAodD{[y`AgPqp@mKwr@ms@umEaW{dAm',
  'b@umAw|@ojBwzDaaJsmBwbEgdCsrFqhAihDquAi`Fux@}_Dui@_eB_u@guCuyAuiHukA_',
  'lKszAu|OmaA{wKm}@clHs_A_rEahCssKo\\sgBsSglAqk@yvDcS_wAyTwpBmPc|BwZknF',
  'oFscB_GsaDiZmyMyLgtHgQonHqT{hKaPg}Dqq@m~Hym@c`EuiBudIabB{hF{pWifx@snA',
  'w`GkFyVqf@y~BkoAi}Lel@wtc@}`@oaXi_C}pZsi@eqGsSuqJ|Lqeb@e]kgPcaAu}SkDw',
  'zGhn@gjYh\\qlNZovJieBqja@ed@siO{[ol\\kCmjMe\\isHorCmec@uLebB}EqiBaCg}',
  '@m@qwHrT_vFps@kkI`uAszIrpHuzYxx@e{Crw@kpDhN{wBtQarDy@knFgP_yCu\\wyCwy',
  'A{kHo~@omEoYmoDaEcPiuAosDagD}rO{{AsyEihCayFilLaiUqm@_bAumFo}DgqA_uByi',
  '@swC~AkzDlhA}xEvcBa}Cxk@ql@`rAo|@~bBq{@``Bye@djDww@z_C_cAtn@ye@nfC_eC',
  '|gGahH~s@w}@``Fi~FpnAooC|u@wlEaEedRlYkrPvKerBfYs}Arg@m}AtrCkzElw@gjBb',
  'h@woBhR{gCwGkgCc[wtCuOapAcFoh@uBy[yBgr@c@iq@o@wvEv@sp@`FajBfCaq@fIipA',
  'dy@ewJlUc`ExGuaBdEmbBpBssArAuqBBg}@s@g{AkB{bBif@_bYmC}r@kDgm@sPq_BuJ_',
  's@{X_{AsK_d@eM{d@wVgx@oWcu@??aDmOkNia@wFoSmDyMyCkPiBePwAob@XcQ|@oNdCo',
  'SfFwXhEmOnLi\\lbAulB`X_d@|k@au@bc@oc@bqC}{BhwDgcD`l@ed@??bL{G|a@eTje@',
  'oS~]cLr~Bgh@|b@}Jv}EieAlv@sPluD{z@nzA_]`|KchCtd@sPvb@wSb{@ko@f`RooQ~e',
  '[upZbuIolI|gFafFzu@iq@nMmJ|OeJn^{Qjh@yQhc@uJ~j@iGdd@kAp~BkBxO{@|QsAfY',
  'gEtYiGd]}Jpd@wRhVoNzNeK`j@ce@vgK}cJnSoSzQkVvUm^rSgc@`Uql@xIq\\vIgg@~k',
  'Dyq[nIir@jNoq@xNwc@fYik@tk@su@neB}uBhqEesFjoGeyHtCoD|D}Ed|@ctAbIuOzqB',
  '_}D~NgY`\\um@v[gm@v{Cw`G`w@o{AdjAwzBh{C}`Gpp@ypAxn@}mAfz@{bBbNia@??jI',
  'ab@`CuOlC}YnAcV`@_^m@aeB}@yk@YuTuBg^uCkZiGk\\yGeY}Lu_@oOsZiTe[uWi[sl@',
  'mo@soAauAsrBgzBqgAglAyd@ig@asAcyAklA}qAwHkGi{@s~@goAmsAyDeEirB_{B}IsJ',
  'uEeFymAssAkdAmhAyTcVkFeEoKiH}l@kp@wg@sj@ku@ey@uh@kj@}EsFmG}Jk^_r@_f@m',
  '~@ym@yjA??a@cFd@kBrCgDbAUnAcBhAyAdk@et@??kF}D??OL'
].join('');
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.map {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.1.3/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Viglino/ol-ext/master/dist/ol-ext.js"></script>
<button id="start-animation">Start Animation</button>
<label for="speed">
      speed:&nbsp;
      <input id="speed" type="range" min="10" max="4999" step="10" value="500">
    </label>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The OpenLayers example doesn't move smoothly as the only coordinates it uses are the points where the linestring changes direction.  Therefore long straights are traversed much faster than the curved sections.  The ol-ext method breaks the linestring into small equal length segments, but it seems to be animating the view to keep up with the marker instead of simply animating the marker.  By reusing the splitLineString function from the second part of the answer to this question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306976/add-image-along-the-linestring to finely divide the linestring and setting only one icon style based on a timer based index it is possible to achieve a smooth movement independently of the view (best seen in a full screen window) and also allows the icon to stay aligned with the direction of travel.

```js
// This long string is placed here due to jsFiddle limitations.
// It is usually loaded with AJAX.
var polyline = [
  'hldhx@lnau`BCG_EaC??cFjAwDjF??uBlKMd@}@z@??aC^yk@z_@se@b[wFdE??wFfE}N',
  'fIoGxB_I\\gG}@eHoCyTmPqGaBaHOoD\\??yVrGotA|N??o[N_STiwAtEmHGeHcAkiA}^',
  'aMyBiHOkFNoI`CcVvM??gG^gF_@iJwC??eCcA]OoL}DwFyCaCgCcCwDcGwHsSoX??wI_E',
  'kUFmq@hBiOqBgTwS??iYse@gYq\\cp@ce@{vA}s@csJqaE}{@iRaqE{lBeRoIwd@_T{]_',
  'Ngn@{PmhEwaA{SeF_u@kQuyAw]wQeEgtAsZ}LiCarAkVwI}D??_}RcjEinPspDwSqCgs@',
  'sPua@_OkXaMeT_Nwk@ob@gV}TiYs[uTwXoNmT{Uyb@wNg]{Nqa@oDgNeJu_@_G}YsFw]k',
  'DuZyDmm@i_@uyIJe~@jCg|@nGiv@zUi_BfNqaAvIow@dEed@dCcf@r@qz@Egs@{Acu@mC',
  'um@yIey@gGig@cK_m@aSku@qRil@we@{mAeTej@}Tkz@cLgr@aHko@qOmcEaJw~C{w@ka',
  'i@qBchBq@kmBS{kDnBscBnFu_Dbc@_~QHeU`IuyDrC_}@bByp@fCyoA?qMbD}{AIkeAgB',
  'k_A_A{UsDke@gFej@qH{o@qGgb@qH{`@mMgm@uQus@kL{_@yOmd@ymBgwE}x@ouBwtA__',
  'DuhEgaKuWct@gp@cnBii@mlBa_@}|Asj@qrCg^eaC}L{dAaJ_aAiOyjByH{nAuYu`GsAw',
  'Xyn@ywMyOyqD{_@cfIcDe}@y@aeBJmwA`CkiAbFkhBlTgdDdPyiB`W}xDnSa}DbJyhCrX',
  'itAhT}x@bE}Z_@qW_Kwv@qKaaAiBgXvIm}A~JovAxCqW~WanB`XewBbK{_A`K}fBvAmi@',
  'xBycBeCauBoF}}@qJioAww@gjHaPopA_NurAyJku@uGmi@cDs[eRaiBkQstAsQkcByNma',
  'CsK_uBcJgbEw@gkB_@ypEqDoqSm@eZcDwjBoGw`BoMegBaU_`Ce_@_uBqb@ytBwkFqiT_',
  'fAqfEwe@mfCka@_eC_UmlB}MmaBeWkkDeHwqAoX}~DcBsZmLcxBqOwqE_DkyAuJmrJ\\o',
  '~CfIewG|YibQxBssB?es@qGciA}RorAoVajA_nAodD{[y`AgPqp@mKwr@ms@umEaW{dAm',
  'b@umAw|@ojBwzDaaJsmBwbEgdCsrFqhAihDquAi`Fux@}_Dui@_eB_u@guCuyAuiHukA_',
  'lKszAu|OmaA{wKm}@clHs_A_rEahCssKo\\sgBsSglAqk@yvDcS_wAyTwpBmPc|BwZknF',
  'oFscB_GsaDiZmyMyLgtHgQonHqT{hKaPg}Dqq@m~Hym@c`EuiBudIabB{hF{pWifx@snA',
  'w`GkFyVqf@y~BkoAi}Lel@wtc@}`@oaXi_C}pZsi@eqGsSuqJ|Lqeb@e]kgPcaAu}SkDw',
  'zGhn@gjYh\\qlNZovJieBqja@ed@siO{[ol\\kCmjMe\\isHorCmec@uLebB}EqiBaCg}',
  '@m@qwHrT_vFps@kkI`uAszIrpHuzYxx@e{Crw@kpDhN{wBtQarDy@knFgP_yCu\\wyCwy',
  'A{kHo~@omEoYmoDaEcPiuAosDagD}rO{{AsyEihCayFilLaiUqm@_bAumFo}DgqA_uByi',
  '@swC~AkzDlhA}xEvcBa}Cxk@ql@`rAo|@~bBq{@``Bye@djDww@z_C_cAtn@ye@nfC_eC',
  '|gGahH~s@w}@``Fi~FpnAooC|u@wlEaEedRlYkrPvKerBfYs}Arg@m}AtrCkzElw@gjBb',
  'h@woBhR{gCwGkgCc[wtCuOapAcFoh@uBy[yBgr@c@iq@o@wvEv@sp@`FajBfCaq@fIipA',
  'dy@ewJlUc`ExGuaBdEmbBpBssArAuqBBg}@s@g{AkB{bBif@_bYmC}r@kDgm@sPq_BuJ_',
  's@{X_{AsK_d@eM{d@wVgx@oWcu@??aDmOkNia@wFoSmDyMyCkPiBePwAob@XcQ|@oNdCo',
  'SfFwXhEmOnLi\\lbAulB`X_d@|k@au@bc@oc@bqC}{BhwDgcD`l@ed@??bL{G|a@eTje@',
  'oS~]cLr~Bgh@|b@}Jv}EieAlv@sPluD{z@nzA_]`|KchCtd@sPvb@wSb{@ko@f`RooQ~e',
  '[upZbuIolI|gFafFzu@iq@nMmJ|OeJn^{Qjh@yQhc@uJ~j@iGdd@kAp~BkBxO{@|QsAfY',
  'gEtYiGd]}Jpd@wRhVoNzNeK`j@ce@vgK}cJnSoSzQkVvUm^rSgc@`Uql@xIq\\vIgg@~k',
  'Dyq[nIir@jNoq@xNwc@fYik@tk@su@neB}uBhqEesFjoGeyHtCoD|D}Ed|@ctAbIuOzqB',
  '_}D~NgY`\\um@v[gm@v{Cw`G`w@o{AdjAwzBh{C}`Gpp@ypAxn@}mAfz@{bBbNia@??jI',
  'ab@`CuOlC}YnAcV`@_^m@aeB}@yk@YuTuBg^uCkZiGk\\yGeY}Lu_@oOsZiTe[uWi[sl@',
  'mo@soAauAsrBgzBqgAglAyd@ig@asAcyAklA}qAwHkGi{@s~@goAmsAyDeEirB_{B}IsJ',
  'uEeFymAssAkdAmhAyTcVkFeEoKiH}l@kp@wg@sj@ku@ey@uh@kj@}EsFmG}Jk^_r@_f@m',
  '~@ym@yjA??a@cFd@kBrCgDbAUnAcBhAyAdk@et@??kF}D??OL'
].join('');


function splitLineString(geometry, minSegmentLength, options) {

  function calculatePointsDistance(coord1, coord2) {
var dx = coord1[0] - coord2[0];
var dy = coord1[1] - coord2[1];
return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  };

  function calculateSplitPointCoords(startNode, nextNode, distanceBetweenNodes, distanceToSplitPoint) {
var d = distanceToSplitPoint / distanceBetweenNodes;
var x = nextNode[0] + (startNode[0] - nextNode[0]) * d;
var y = nextNode[1] + (startNode[1] - nextNode[1]) * d;
return [x, y];
  };

  function calculateAngle(startNode, nextNode, alwaysUp) {
var x = (startNode[0] - nextNode[0]);
var y = (startNode[1] - nextNode[1]);
var angle = Math.atan(x/y);
if (!alwaysUp) {
   angle = y > 0 ? angle + Math.PI : x < 0 ? angle + Math.PI*2 : angle;
}
return angle;
  };

  var splitPoints = [];
  var coords = geometry.getCoordinates();

  var coordIndex = 0;
  var startPoint = coords[coordIndex];
  var nextPoint = coords[coordIndex + 1];
  var angle = calculateAngle(startPoint, nextPoint, options.alwaysUp);

  var n = Math.ceil(geometry.getLength()/minSegmentLength);
  var segmentLength = geometry.getLength() / n;
  var currentSegmentLength = options.midPoints ? segmentLength/2 : segmentLength;
 
  for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {

var distanceBetweenPoints = calculatePointsDistance(startPoint, nextPoint);
currentSegmentLength += distanceBetweenPoints;

if (currentSegmentLength < segmentLength) {
  coordIndex++;
  if(coordIndex < coords.length - 1) {
    startPoint = coords[coordIndex];
    nextPoint = coords[coordIndex + 1];
    angle = calculateAngle(startPoint, nextPoint, options.alwaysUp);
    i--;
    continue;
  } else {
    if (!options.midPoints) {
      var splitPointCoords = nextPoint;
      splitPointCoords.push(angle);
      splitPoints.push(splitPointCoords);
    }
    break;
  }
} else {
  var distanceToSplitPoint = currentSegmentLength - segmentLength;
  var splitPointCoords = calculateSplitPointCoords(startPoint, nextPoint, distanceBetweenPoints, distanceToSplitPoint);
  startPoint = splitPointCoords.slice();
  splitPointCoords.push(angle);
  splitPoints.push(splitPointCoords);
  currentSegmentLength = 0;
}
  }

  return splitPoints;
};

var route = new ol.format.Polyline({
  factor: 1e6
}).readGeometry(polyline, {
  dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
  featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
});

var routeCoords = route.getCoordinates();
var routeLength = routeCoords.length;

var routeFeature = new ol.Feature({
  type: 'route',
  geometry: route
});
var startMarker = new ol.Feature({
  type: 'icon',
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(routeCoords[0])
});
var endMarker = new ol.Feature({
  type: 'icon',
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(routeCoords[routeLength - 1])
});

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source:  new ol.source.OSM() 
});

var repeat = false;
var timer = -1;

var style = function(feature, resolution) {

  if (feature.get('type') == 'route') {

var styles = [
  new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      width: 6,
      color: [237, 212, 0, 0.8],
    })
  })
];

if (timer < 0) {
  feature.unset('splitPoints', true);
} else {
  var splitPoints = feature.get('splitPoints');
  if (!splitPoints) {
    splitPoints = splitLineString(feature.getGeometry(), 2 * resolution, {alwaysUp: false, midPoints: true});
    feature.set('splitPoints', splitPoints, true);
  }
  if (!repeat && timer >= splitPoints.length) {
    stopAnimation(true);
  } else {
    var index = timer % splitPoints.length;
    var point = splitPoints[index];
    styles.push(
      new ol.style.Style({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point([point[0],point[1]]),
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
          src: 'https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-color-round/3/19-32.png',
          rotation: point[2]
        }),
        zIndex: 1
      })
    );
  }
}
return styles;

  } else {

return [
  new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      anchor: [0.5, 1],
      src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/data/icon.png',
    })
  })
];

  }

}

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
features: [routeFeature, startMarker, endMarker]
  }),
  style: style
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster, vector],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
center: [-5639523.95, -3501274.52],
zoom: 10
  })
});


var animating = false;
var token;
var speedInput = document.getElementById('speed');
var startButton = document.getElementById('start-animation');

function startAnimation() {

  if (animating) {
stopAnimation(false);
  } else {

animating = true;
startButton.textContent = 'Cancel Animation';
token = setInterval( function(){
  timer++;
  vector.setStyle(style);
}, 6000/speedInput.value);

  }
}

function stopAnimation(ended) {
  animating = false;
  startButton.textContent = 'Start Animation';
  clearInterval(token);
  timer = -1;
  if (!ended) {
vector.setStyle(style);
  }
}

startButton.addEventListener('click', startAnimation, false);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.map {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<label for="speed">
      speed:&nbsp;
      <input id="speed" type="range" min="10" max="999" step="10" value="200">
    </label>
<button id="start-animation">Start Animation</button>
```